# Extract array from Json object

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to extract an array from Json Object using GSON library.

I've already tried to create class and let Gson library do the work but in this particular case It doesn't work.

Class for extracted data

```
public class Images {
        private Image[] images;

        public class Image {
            private String url;

            public Image(String url) {
                this.url = url;
            }

            public String getUrl() {
                return url;
            }
        }

        public Images(Image[] images) {
            this.images = images;
        }

        public Image[] getImages() {
            return images;
        }
    }
```

Example data

```
...
,
"images": [
   {
     "url": "https://a.allegroimg.com/original/030516/a867b9dd4021b15678fc03a3981b"
    },
    {
       "url": "https://a.allegroimg.com/original/03da09/19740f7147ad929609cc2bcc499e"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://a.allegroimg.com/original/03198b/c024c7e448cab876bb49ad055567"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://a.allegroimg.com/original/039fee/64bae4c64dac89e5b5b4d001c2ca"
     }
],
...
```

I'm getting error: "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 283 path $.items.promoted[0].images"

I'm asking for help with extracting data from json object.

## Edit

I just needed to remove class 'Images' and save 'urls' from Json to Image[]

Comment: is this the complete json? or you just breaked it and posted ? and on `Images` you need no arg constructor with setter method

Comment: It's just a part, with the rest I have no problem, just with this one

Answer (score 0):

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 283 path $.items.promoted[0].images

The issue is due to the wrapper class `Images`. From the error, I think your object is something like this:

```java
class Promoted {
  private Images images;
  ..
}

class Images {
  private Image[] images;
}
```

In your current form, the json that you would be able to parse is:

```
...
,
"images": {
  "images": [
    {
      "url": "https://a.allegroimg.com/original/030516/a867b9dd4021b15678fc03a3981b"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://a.allegroimg.com/original/03da09/19740f7147ad929609cc2bcc499e"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://a.allegroimg.com/original/03198b/c024c7e448cab876bb49ad055567"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://a.allegroimg.com/original/039fee/64bae4c64dac89e5b5b4d001c2ca"
    }
  ]
}
...
```

Instead, you can directly embed the array `Image[]` in the parent object (without the wrapper class):

```java
class Promoted {
  private Image[] images;
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DSM](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm/) library. By using it you can extract a part of JSON while you reading JSON data.

First of all, you must define your mapping in yaml format.

Mapping Definition:

```
 result:
   type: array  # expect result as array
   path: /images
   fields:
     url:
```

Use DSM to read data.

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/config.yaml")).create();
Object object=dsm.toObject(new File("path/to/data.json");
System.out.println(object);
```

Here is the output:

```
[{url=https://a.allegroimg.com/original/030516/a867b9dd4021b15678fc03a3981b}, {url=https://a.allegroimg.com/original/03da09/19740f7147ad929609cc2bcc499e}, {url=https://a.allegroimg.com/original/03198b/c024c7e448cab876bb49ad055567}, {url=https://a.allegroimg.com/original/039fee/64bae4c64dac89e5b5b4d001c2ca}]
```

if you want to get all **url** field as a list you can charge your mapping definition as follows.

```
result:
   type: array
   path: /images/url
```

Output of this mapping is :

```
[https://a.allegroimg.com/original/030516/a867b9dd4021b15678fc03a3981b, https://a.allegroimg.com/original/03da09/19740f7147ad929609cc2bcc499e, https://a.allegroimg.com/original/03198b/c024c7e448cab876bb49ad055567, https://a.allegroimg.com/original/039fee/64bae4c64dac89e5b5b4d001c2ca]
```

Comment: He needs to use Gson, and it is possible with Gson, so why use another library?

Comment: As I understand from this question he only wants URL list.  If you use DSM you don't need to write Java (Images and image ) class. To get only urls from json you have to make custom deserialiser in Gson.  DSM  allows you  write custom deserialiser in declarative way  with mapping definitions.   Developing with DSM is faster and needs very less code. This is some reason to change Gson to DSM.  By the way DSM work for both XML and JSON.